# Fabricjs object controls visible outside canvas

Tags: html5-canvas, fabricjs

I am using fabric.js for html 5 interactive canvas app. If the object scales larger than the canvas, the controls go invisible outside canvas. How to make it visible outside the canvas or is there a way to style those controllers in css.

Comment: How about just making a second fabric.Canvas for the controls?

Comment: can you fiddle it for me? I dont know how.

Comment: How to create a second canvas: `var controlsCanvas=new fabric.Canvas('myControlCanvasElement');`  Then just put your controls on this second canvas as you have already done on your primary canvas.  The User-Interface goes on the second canvas but the code points to the primary canvas.

Comment: thats ok. But the controls are created along with the objects. how do i separate controls from the objects to put in other canvas?

Comment: Maybe my bad :-/...Have you created your own user-interface controls using fabricjs objects or are you talking about the built-in fabricjs resizer-rotator control?  If it's the latter, you can't force the built-in controls to always be visible on-canvas.  If it's the former, you can reference the primary canvas in response to user manipulations of the controls on the secondary canvas.

Comment: I am using built in controls. So i cant force it visible outside canvas. Ok how about If I clip the canvas an make the controls visible outside the clip. is it possible?

Comment: You could listen for the 'moving' event on an object and respond by resetting the position of that object to always have enough margin vs the canvas edge to make its controls visible.

Comment: @markE : Hi,  I did clippping the canvas thing but now I got another problem,I want to resize that clipped portion like scale it up or down, is it possible?

Answer (score 3):

So, in fabricjs controls are rendered on the canvas, so having controls outside canvas it is not possible.

You can still obtain the effect in this way, this is just a trace.

Make canvas big as 100% of window, or anyway very bigger than drawing area.
Then you can clip the drawing canvas with a rectangle.
If you need borders to define the drawing area you can still put an overlay image as fabricjs allow you.

If you need to have controls near the drawing canvas you will have to position them OVER the non drawing part of the canvas.

This will give you some additional tasks:
When you create some object you have to be sure that they go in the drawing area. If you consider position of objects, you have to consider that a translation has to be applied, because you have absolute position while user will position the object watching a fake top left corner of a drawing area and not the top left corner of the canvas.

Comment: I'm a little late to the party, but have the same issue. Is there some fiddle I can follow, because I can't figure it out.

Comment: Start a question with your own stack overflow snippet so that we can see what is not working out for you

Answer (score 1):

The best thing you can do is make a larger canvas, but limit the drawing area to a limited part, like a margin. Not easy because after that you always need to consider the margin when making other calculations, but it is possible.