# Is this possible in fabricjs to show boundaries of bounding rectangle outside canvas?

Tags: fabricjs

Is this possible in fabricjs to show boundaries of bounding rectangle outside canvas as shown in the attached image.[image]

Comment: There is no easy way to do this. See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/24719855/5045563

Comment: Thanks shkaper. I will try the way the link you suggested.

Comment: Definitely possible, but not fun. You will forever have to manage your own "virtual" drawing area. There will be a lot more code and documentation to maintain.